Cant get claims in authorization handler
public class RequestLoginIsUserLoginHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AccessRequirement, string>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AccessRequirement requirement, string resource)
    {
        string? name = context.User.Identity?.Name;
        if (name == resource)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

I can see claims values in database, but context.User.Identity?.Name is always null.
image
Im using cookies authentication. Im adding claim this way:
var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, input.Login),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user")
        };
await userManager.AddClaimsAsync(user, claims);

Maybe I have problems here:
[HttpPost("/login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string login, string password)
    {
        var user = await mediator.Send(new GetUserByLoginQuery(login));
        if (user is null) return Unauthorized("wrong login");

        var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, false, false);
        if(!result.Succeeded) 
        {
            return Unauthorized("wrong password");
        }
        return Ok();
    }

I tried to use ClaimTypes.Name and my own type "Name". Result is the same.
Updated. I add claims during registration. Code:
[HttpPost("/register")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUser(RegisterInput input)
    {
        var userWithSameLogin = await mediator.Send(new GetUserByLoginQuery(input.Login));
        if (userWithSameLogin != null)
        {
            return Conflict();
        }

        var user = new User
        {
            UserName = input.Login,
            FirstName = input.FirstName,
            LastName = input.LastName,
            PhoneNumber = input.PhoneNumber,
            Email = input.Email
        };
        
        var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, input.Password);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return BadRequest(result.Errors);
        }
        
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, input.Login),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user")
        };
        await userManager.AddClaimsAsync(user, claims);

        return Ok();
    }


You are getting this issue might be because claim is not properly attached to the authentication principal or when they are not being correctly loaded during the authentication process.
you could try this below sample code to make the claim being added correctly s it does not shows null:
Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

// Add Identity services
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

// Configure Cookie Authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
    });

AccountController.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Security.Claims;
using CookieAuthDemo1.Models;

namespace CookieAuthDemo1.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

        public AccountController(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Login);
            if (user == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login.");
                return View(model);
            }

            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, false, false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim>
           {
               new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
               new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user")
           };
                var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true };

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid password.");
            return View(model);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
    }





I add claims using UserManager during registration (I added my CreateUser method in question body).  I updated my code using your way of adding claims and it worked. Thanks. But I still dont understand why my code is unacceptable.

@DaniilKozenko when you login using SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync, it doesn't automatically include all claims from the database into the HttpContext.User. By default, it only includes a few essential claims. This is why context.User.Identity?.Name was null—the Name claim wasn't included unless you explicitly added it after login.The claims you added during registration are stored in the database, but they are not automatically attached to the ClaimsPrincipal during login unless you retrieve and add them manually.

In my code after successfully authenticating the user with SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync, i have manually add the claims to a ClaimsIdentity and then sign the user in with these claims. This ensures that all the claims you want are included in the authentication cookie and are available via HttpContext.User throughout the user's session. let me know if you still have any  question or concern
